# Referencing a parameter to function in header file

Tags: c++, pointers, com, header

Doing some directx programming. I'm self taught, some that means that unknown educational holes pop-up where most "convenient". Answers of any type are appreciated. You know, tear the code apart! xD

I'm encapsulating code into a static library to take away the horrific view of my test-and-go code. I've defined the header as such:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "windowsx.h"

#include "D3D11.h"
#include "D3Dx11.h"
#include "D3DX10.h"

//Infinity Machine Library

#pragma comment (lib, "D3D11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "D3Dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "D3Dx10.lib")

namespace InfinityEngine{

HWND hWnd;
HRESULT Compile_Monitor;
struct VERTEX{ 
float x,y,z;D3DXCOLOR Color;
};

//Initialize Graphics
void BuildBufferDescription(){
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC BufferDescription;
ZeroMemory(&BufferDescription, sizeof(BufferDescription));

BufferDescription.Usage                   =D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
BufferDescription.ByteWidth               =sizeof(VERTEX)*3;
BufferDescription.BindFlags               =D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
BufferDescription.CPUAccessFlags          =D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
BufferDescription.MiscFlags               =0;
}

void BuildSubresourceData(VERTEX VertStruct[]){
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA SRData;
ZeroMemory(&SRData, sizeof(SRData));
SRData.pSysMem=VertStruct;
}

void CreateBuffer(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC BufferDescription,
              D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA SRData,
              ID3D11Buffer* D3DBuffer,
              ID3D11Device* Device){
Compile_Monitor = Device->CreateBuffer(&BufferDescription, &SRData, &D3DBuffer);
    if(FAILED(Compile_Monitor))
{
   MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateBuffer() failed. Check for: \n Possible Bad or NULL value in     D3D11_BUFFER_DESC struct.", 
                    L"Program Error!", 
                    MB_OK);
   PostQuitMessage(0);
}
}

void MaptoVideoMemory(ID3D11Buffer* D3DBuffer, 
                  D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource,
                  ID3D11DeviceContext* DeviceContext){
Compile_Monitor = DeviceContext->Map(D3DBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &MappedResource);
    if(FAILED(Compile_Monitor))
{
   MessageBox(hWnd, L"Map() failed.", 
                    L"Program Error!", 
                    MB_OK);
   PostQuitMessage(0);
}
}

void CopyBuffer(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource,
            VERTEX VertStruct[]){
memcpy(MappedResource.pData, VertStruct, sizeof(VertStruct));
}
```

(Example of header format)

Ok. Well, a noob pointer problem came up when trying to declare a function from the header which I pass several COM objects to:

```
void InitializeD3D(HWND hWnd,
         IDXGISwapChain *Swapchain,
         ID3D11Device *Device,
         ID3D11DeviceContext *DeviceContext,
         ID3D11RenderTargetView *RenderTargetView,
         int ScreenWidth,
         int ScreenHeight){ ...
```

I call the function parameters in the main cpp file, using &Swapchain, &Device... as such:

```
   InitializeD3D(hWnd,&Swapchain,&Device,&DeviceContext,&RenderTargetView,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight);
```

Of course the function expects a type in the format(ie): ID3D11Device** but what I'm passing is read as ID3D11Device*.

### I think I have an understanding of pointers in general, but am missing something fundamental - especially as I'm a bit nervous when implementing knowledge of them. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

The initial D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain() declaration:

```
HRESULT WINAPI D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
__in_opt IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter,
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE DriverType,
HMODULE Software,
UINT Flags,
__in_ecount_opt( FeatureLevels ) CONST D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL* pFeatureLevels,
UINT FeatureLevels,
UINT SDKVersion,
__in_opt CONST DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC* pSwapChainDesc,
__out_opt IDXGISwapChain** ppSwapChain,
__out_opt ID3D11Device** ppDevice,
__out_opt D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL* pFeatureLevel,
__out_opt ID3D11DeviceContext** ppImmediateContext );
```

It takes a pointer to a pointer for ID3D11Device, which I fill by &Device of the respective type. When D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain() is moved to a header, inside of a function, &Device no longer works as a parameter, and calls for a ID3D11Device** .

---

Edit:

```
void InitializeD3D(HWND hWnd,
         IDXGISwapChain* Swapchain,
         ID3D11Device* Device,
         ID3D11DeviceContext* DeviceContext,
         ID3D11RenderTargetView* RenderTargetView,
         int ScreenWidth,
         int ScreenHeight){
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC SwapChainDesc;
ZeroMemory(&SwapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

SwapChainDesc.BufferCount           = 1;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format     = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width      = ScreenWidth;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height     = ScreenHeight;
SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage           = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;    
SwapChainDesc.OutputWindow          = hWnd;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator   =60;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator =1;
SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count      = 4;
SwapChainDesc.Windowed              = TRUE;
SwapChainDesc.Flags                 = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

Compile_Monitor = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
                              D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                              &SwapChainDesc,
                              &Swapchain,
                              &Device,
                              NULL,
                              &DeviceContext);
if(FAILED(Compile_Monitor))
{
   MessageBox(hWnd, L"D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain() failed.", 
                    L"Program Error!", 
                    MB_OK);
}

ID3D11Texture2D *Texture2d;
Swapchain->GetBuffer(0,__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D),(LPVOID*)&Texture2d);

Device->CreateRenderTargetView(Texture2d,NULL,&RenderTargetView);
Texture2d->Release();

DeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &RenderTargetView, NULL);

D3D11_VIEWPORT Viewport;
ZeroMemory(&Viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

Viewport.Height     =ScreenHeight;
Viewport.Width      =ScreenWidth;
Viewport.MaxDepth   =1.0;
Viewport.MinDepth   =0.0;
Viewport.TopLeftX   =0;
Viewport.TopLeftY   =0;
DeviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &Viewport);
}
```

Above is my InitializeD3D() from static header.

Comment: What's the question? *"Can I pass arbitrary types to a function in a strongly typed language?"*? Your compiler already answered that question for you.

Comment: Specifically, I declared "ID3D11Device *Device" locally and wrote the parameter in as &Device. The compiler says that "the argument of type ID3D11Device** is incompatible with parameter of type ID3D11Device**"

My header function declaration calls for ID3D11Device* Device.

Comment: Here's a better er... clearer question... I'm confused with declaring pointers in the header and wondered if any changes must be made. (The program works when altogether in one document.)

Comment: I think I may be catching up to your point. I'll research "arbitrary types".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `InitializeD3D` takes a pointer to a pointer to a `ID3D11Device`. And you're only passing a single pointer.

`ID3D11Device` is an *interface*; you shouldn't ever be directly creating an instance of it. You should only declare a pointer to the interface, then pass the address of that pointer into `InitializeD3D`, and then (if successful) your pointer will have been assigned a valid address.

```
    ID3D11Device *pDevice = NULL;
    InitializeD3D(hWnd,&Swapchain,&pDevice,&DeviceContext,
                  &RenderTargetView,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to implement this. Additionally I think some research further into interfaces will help my understanding a bit. I'll return whether it fixes it.

Comment: I didn't create a direct instance of ID3D11Device, I called it's pointer. In particular, the call to D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain() fails, due to pointer misdirection. I've edited the initial post abit (See bottom)

Comment: I'm about to mark this down as answer. I've one last question: How would I pass in &Swapchain to a custom function?

Comment: You should change the `Swapchain`, `Device` and `DeviceContext` parameters to double pointers. As it is, whoever calls `InitializeD3D` is passing the pointers *by value*. So although `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` will modify the pointers, they will be lost once `InitializeD3D` exits. You need double pointers in your custom function for the same reason that you need them for the DirectX function. Or, instead of double pointers, you could pass the pointers by reference; that would have the same effect. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: This was an awesome pointer lesson. Thanks so much guys! Trying to follow along with the suggestions, I ve learned more about OOP principals. I'm going to rewrite the header so instead of basic function calls, It'll utilize more class inheritance to sustain data.